# Robots always make extra rotations in automatic navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning auto-navigation in the simulator, I set a target point in Rviz that is very close to the starting position. The robot then begins to spin and the console tells me that he is clearing the costmap and that he still cannot reach the target point after multiple rotations. The console then displays oscillating over and over. I want to know how to avoid this rotation. Which program trigger this clearing action?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314592/robots-always-make-extra-rotations-in-automatic-navigation/) by [mydansun](https://answers.ros.org/users/38274/mydansun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2019-02-04**:
Not a lot of definitive info in your post. I assume you are useing [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters). Read the wiki, there are parameters to disable recovery behaviors. Like `clearing_rotation_allowed` . If the robot is consistently over turning try setting limits to acceleration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very little information to go with. So I have to make some assumptions. I assume the robot starts to rotate immediately after setting the goal and the goal you set is in the free space and the robot is not too close to any obstacle/wall.  This behavior could very well be a problem with Gazebo (if you are using gazebo) simulator generating spurious laser returns near the robot.

If this is your scenario, the best way is to visualize your laser data and local costmap in Rviz and see if the simulation generates these noise. I faced this several times and one solution is to reduce the frequency of the laser in the urdf specification.

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2019-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1